# Qt creator cannot find, QTcpServer and QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Eventhough, I put 'network' in .pro file,

My Qt creator cannot find QTcpSocket and QTcpServer.

What should I do?

I remove the Qtcreator and redownloaded already but it also did not work.

My Linux version is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

and I downloaded QT Creator by linux commands.

sudo apt-get install qtcreator

I even do the linus updates because I worried that I missed something.

sudo get-apt update
sudo get-apt upgrade

Why Qtcreator cannot perceive QTcpServer and QTcpSocket headers?

--------------*.pro -----------------------------------

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = server11
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

---

-------------------mainwindow.h--------------------------------------

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

Comment: Did you try #include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>? Meybe you need to install full Qt, not only QtCreator?

Comment: But what it exactly means full Qt?

Comment: Wow!! <QtNetwork/QTcpServer> is working!!!! Really, Thank you! I spent about 3hours to fix this problem. Thank you!!

Comment: That's a non-solution. `#include <QTcpServer>` *must* work as-is, if it's not working there's something else missing.

Comment: Oh, really? I do not know what is missing...

Comment: After you change the contents of the `.pro` file, you **must** right-click on the topmost project node in the Creator's project explorer and select "Run qmake". That would have fixed the problem. The <QtNetwork/foo> style of includes is from Qt 4 and is deprecated in Qt 5. They simply mask trivial problems like yours. Alternatively, you could delete the shadow build folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the complete framework? Or just the IDE?

Try downloading the Qt offline installer and downloading the framework through it. Download and install it from here.

[Qt Open Source](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

[Instructions for Ubuntu](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu)